# Office 365 events list request returns only two events

Tags: outlook-restapi

For some of our users that connected office 365 calendar via oauth 2.0 we get only one or two event from calendar. But user clearly have more and we requested for more.

Request url looks like this `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/[calendar_id]/events?$top=40&$orderby=start/dateTime+ASC`
Do we miss some parameters?

And response also valid but didn't contain `@odata.nextLink`

```
{u'@odata.context': u"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Calendars('AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgEGAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQERZAAAAA%3D%3D')/Events",
 u'value': [{u'@odata.etag': u'W/"rFj7uJT+UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAAEFHg=="',
             u'@odata.id': u"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('00034001-13f3-1256-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')/Events('AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgENAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQEJeQAAAA==')",
             u'Attendees': [],
             u'Body': {u'Content': u'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\r\n<meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">\r\n<style type="text/css" style="display:none">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir="ltr">\r\n<div id="divtagdefaultwrapper" dir="ltr" style="font-size:12pt; color:#000000; font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif">\r\n<p style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px"><br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n',
                       u'ContentType': u'HTML'},
             u'BodyPreview': u'',
             u'Calendar@odata.associationLink': u"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('00034001-13f3-1256-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')/Calendars('AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgEGAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQERZAAAAA==')/$ref",
             u'Calendar@odata.navigationLink': u"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('00034001-13f3-1256-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')/Calendars('AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgEGAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQERZAAAAA==')",
             u'Categories': [],
             u'ChangeKey': u'rFj7uJT+UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAAEFHg==',
             u'CreatedDateTime': u'2018-10-24T21:32:39.9808765Z',
             u'End': {u'DateTime': u'2018-10-26T16:00:00.0000000',
                      u'TimeZone': u'UTC'},
             u'HasAttachments': False,
             u'Id': u'AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgENAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQEJeQAAAA==',
             u'Importance': u'Normal',
             u'IsAllDay': False,
             u'IsCancelled': False,
             u'IsOnlineMeeting': False,
             u'IsOrganizer': True,
             u'IsReminderOn': True,
             u'IsRoomRequested': False,
             u'LastModifiedDateTime': u'2018-10-24T21:32:40.0829497Z',
             u'Location': {u'Address': {u'Type': u'Unknown'},
                           u'Coordinates': {},
                           u'DisplayName': u'',
                           u'LocationType': u'Default',
                           u'UniqueIdType': u'Unknown'},
             u'Locations': [],
             u'OnlineMeeting': None,
             u'OnlineMeetingProvider': u'Unknown',
             u'OnlineMeetingUrl': None,
             u'Organizer': {u'EmailAddress': {u'Address': u'outlook_72A9F50C7E660380@outlook.com',
                                              u'Name': u'Ray Burt'}},
             u'OriginalEndTimeZone': u'Pacific Standard Time',
             u'OriginalStartTimeZone': u'Pacific Standard Time',
             u'Recurrence': None,
             u'ReminderMinutesBeforeStart': 15,
             u'ResponseRequested': True,
             u'ResponseStatus': {u'Response': u'Organizer',
                                 u'Time': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'},
             u'Sensitivity': u'Normal',
             u'SeriesMasterId': None,
             u'ShowAs': u'Busy',
             u'Start': {u'DateTime': u'2018-10-26T15:30:00.0000000',
                        u'TimeZone': u'UTC'},
             u'Subject': u'call dara re buyout',
             u'Type': u'SingleInstance',
             u'WebLink': u'https://outlook.live.com/owa/?itemid=AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT%2BUEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgENAAAArFj7uJT%2BUEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQEJeQAAAA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item',
             u'iCalUId': u'040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000002FAF1717E16BD4010000000000000000100000000FE017796D4AC64FB04180CD43A0215A'},
            {u'@odata.etag': u'W/"rFj7uJT+UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAAECWw=="',
             u'@odata.id': u"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('00034001-13f3-1256-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')/Events('AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgENAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQEJeAAAAA==')",
             u'Attendees': [],
             u'Body': {u'Content': u'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\r\n<meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div>call No ca Dev dis</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n',
                       u'ContentType': u'HTML'},
             u'BodyPreview': u'call No ca Dev dis',
             u'Calendar@odata.associationLink': u"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('00034001-13f3-1256-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')/Calendars('AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgEGAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQERZAAAAA==')/$ref",
             u'Calendar@odata.navigationLink': u"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('00034001-13f3-1256-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')/Calendars('AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgEGAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQERZAAAAA==')",
             u'Categories': [],
             u'ChangeKey': u'rFj7uJT+UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAAECWw==',
             u'CreatedDateTime': u'2018-10-24T20:51:40.6964914Z',
             u'End': {u'DateTime': u'2018-10-28T15:30:00.0000000',
                      u'TimeZone': u'UTC'},
             u'HasAttachments': False,
             u'Id': u'AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgENAAAArFj7uJT_UEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQEJeAAAAA==',
             u'Importance': u'Normal',
             u'IsAllDay': False,
             u'IsCancelled': False,
             u'IsOnlineMeeting': False,
             u'IsOrganizer': True,
             u'IsReminderOn': True,
             u'IsRoomRequested': False,
             u'LastModifiedDateTime': u'2018-10-24T20:51:40.8245872Z',
             u'Location': {u'Address': {u'Type': u'Unknown'},
                           u'Coordinates': {},
                           u'DisplayName': u'',
                           u'LocationType': u'Default',
                           u'UniqueIdType': u'Unknown'},
             u'Locations': [],
             u'OnlineMeeting': None,
             u'OnlineMeetingProvider': u'Unknown',
             u'OnlineMeetingUrl': None,
             u'Organizer': {u'EmailAddress': {u'Address': u'outlook_72A9F50C7E660380@outlook.com',
                                              u'Name': u'Ray Burt'}},
             u'OriginalEndTimeZone': u'Pacific Standard Time',
             u'OriginalStartTimeZone': u'Pacific Standard Time',
             u'Recurrence': None,
             u'ReminderMinutesBeforeStart': 15,
             u'ResponseRequested': True,
             u'ResponseStatus': {u'Response': u'Organizer',
                                 u'Time': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'},
             u'Sensitivity': u'Normal',
             u'SeriesMasterId': None,
             u'ShowAs': u'Busy',
             u'Start': {u'DateTime': u'2018-10-28T15:00:00.0000000',
                        u'TimeZone': u'UTC'},
             u'Subject': u'call No ca Dev dis',
             u'Type': u'SingleInstance',
             u'WebLink': u'https://outlook.live.com/owa/?itemid=AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xM2YzLTEyNTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADVjbLhYhdeE6H1zpTSH6o9gcArFj7uJT%2BUEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAgENAAAArFj7uJT%2BUEaLZdTP1QUacAAAAQEJeAAAAA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item',
             u'iCalUId': u'040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000DDAA3E5DDB6BD4010000000000000000100000009DA34F8D54261A4FBF040805204F06CF'}]}
```

What we do wrong?
Why we didn't have `@odata.nextLink`?